# Click event fired twice

Tags: jquery, colorbox, raphael

I don't know if this is to do with Raphael, ColorBox or jQuery. Here's my the relevant code:

```
var image = paper.image(p.url_, tx, ty, img.width, img.height);
image[0].style.cursor = "pointer";
image.node.onclick = function() {
    $.colorbox({
        title: "Some Random Title",
        href: function() {
            $.post("test.php", { arg: p.id_ } );
        }
    });
};
```

When watching the click in FireBug console the post is fired twice. It is also fired twice if it is a get as well.

If I change from the href function to a direct call of test.php then there is only a single get issued.

Why is the click event issuing the call twice when using jQuery?

**UPDATE**: Adding a call to alert in the anonymous function also fires twice so I guess it is something to do with colorbox.

**UPDATE 2**: Just tried wiring it to an actual page and FireBug spits this error message out in addition to the two get/posts. Which confirms this is a problem in ColorBox. Also it makes progress hard because while both calls complete colorbox sits showing it's throbber.

```
c is undefined 
    (function(b,gb){var v="none",t="click"...c.settings=eb;b(c.init)})(jQuery,this)
```

Note: This only attached to the second call and not the first.

Comment: did you tried "image `[0]`.node.onclick = function() {};" ??

Comment: I hadn't but I just did and FireBug reports `image[0].node is undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not terribly familiar with colorbox so I am going out on a limb here. I'm guessing you want colorbox's html to use the result of the post. I would put the post outside of color box. Is there any reason you aren't using `$(image.node).click()`? Or even `$(image).click()`? Here's how I would do it

```
var image = paper.image(p.url_, tx, ty, img.width, img.height);
image[0].style.cursor = "pointer";
$(image.node).click(function() {
    var post_html = $.post("test.php", { arg: p.id_ } );
    $.colorbox({
        title: "Some Random Title",
        html: post_html
    });
});
```

This may not fix it, but it will tell you if the problem is that colorbox fires the href twice or if the click is being executed twice.

Comment: The reason for using the `image.node.click` is because it is provided by Raphael for the purpose of making element clickable and seemed the logical way to go.  I will try your way and report back.

Comment: Actually you were nearly there.  I've corrected your example and given you the tick.  However with this method there is a noticeable lag between the click and appearance of the lightbox and also due to the loading be done outside of the box you no longer get the throbber.